# Tkinter Значение чекбоксов

Tags: python, tkinter

Здравствуйте, не получается достать состояния чекбоксов, ну точнее я их получаю  но неправильные (то есть при выборе некоторых чекбоксов на форме и в последствие пытаясь определить их состояние я его получаю но не верно), не пойму почему. Просто без класса точно таким же способом я получаю верные значения состояний.

```
from tkinter import*
class Test:
    all_answer = []


    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master, height=200, width=300)
        frame.pack_propagate(0)
        frame.pack()
        self.addButton = Button(frame, text="Add new test", command=self.new_test)
        self.addButton.place(x=10, y=90)
        self.lblnumber = Label(frame, text="Enter number quest: ")
        self.lblnumber.place(x=10, y=20)
        self.number = Entry(frame)
        self.number.place(x=130, y=20)

        self.lblanswer = Label(frame, text="Enter number answer: ")
        self.lblanswer.place(x=10, y=60)
        self.number_of_answer1 = Entry(frame)
        self.number_of_answer1.place(x=130, y=60)

    def new_test(self):
        root = Tk()
        s = int(self.number.get())
        s1 = int(self.number_of_answer1.get())

        frame = Frame(root, height=1000, width=500)
        frame.pack_propagate(0)
        frame.pack()
        states = []
        for i in range(s):
            for z in range(s1):
                var = IntVar()
                chk = Checkbutton(frame, text=str(z), variable=var)
                chk.grid(row=i, column=z)
                states.append(var)
        addTest = Button(frame, text="PRINT")
        addTest.grid(row=s+1,column=0)
        addTest.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.kkk(states))

    def kkk(self, all):
        a = [int(item.get()) for index, item in enumerate(all)]
        print(a)


root = Tk()
b = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def new_test(self):
    # root = Tk()  # ошибка тут !!!
    s = int(self.number.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот в таком виде все отлично, а в классе не работает.

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
states = []
for i in range(2):
    for z in range(4):
        var = BooleanVar()
        chk = Checkbutton(root, text=str(z), variable=var)
        chk.grid(row=i, column=z)
        states.append(var)
addTest = Button(root, text="PRINT")
addTest.grid(row=3,column=0)
addTest.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: kkk(states))

def kkk( aaa):
    a = [bool(item.get()) for index, item in enumerate(aaa)]
    print(a)

root.mainloop()
```